# On the equivalence of different assumptions of Hidden Markov Models (HMM)

Tags: markov-chains, conditional-probability, transition-matrix, hidden-markov-models

I am currently studying Hidden Markov Models (HMM). We denote the hidden quantities as $(X_0, \dots, X_n) \in \mathcal{X}^{n+1}$ and the observed quantities $(Y_1, \dots, Y_n) \in \mathcal{Y}^n$. The usual assumption for HMMs is that the joint density of these random variables simplifies in the following way

$$
\begin{aligned}
&p(X_0 = x_0, \dots, X_n = x_n, Y_1 = y_1, \dots, Y_n = y_n) \\
&=
\underbrace{p(X_0 = x_0)}_{\text{distribution of initial states}} \cdot 
\prod_{n=1}^n
\underbrace{p(Y_i = y_i \,|\, X_i = x_i)}_{\text{emission probabilities}} \cdot \underbrace{p(X_i = x_i \,|\, X_{i-1} = x_{i-1})}_{\text{transition probabilities}}
\end{aligned}.
$$
This main assumption can be derived from the following assumptions.

- **A1.** $(X_0, \dots, X_n)$ is a Markov, i.e. $p(X_n = x_n\,|\, X_{n-1} = x_{n-1}, \dots, X_{0} = x_0) = p(X_n = x_n\,|\, X_{n-1} = x_{n-1})$.
- **A2.** $p(Y_1 = y_1, \dots, Y_n = y_n \,|\, X_n = x_0, \dots, X_0 = x_0) = \prod_{i=1}^n p(Y_i = y_i \,|\, X_i = x_i)$.

In turn, assumption **A2.** can clearly be replaced by the following two assumptions.

- **A2.1.** The random variables $Y_1, \dots, Y_n$ are conditionally independent given $X_0, \dots, X_n$, i.e. $$p(Y_1 = y_1, \dots, Y_n = y_n \,|\, X_n = x_n, \dots, X_0 = x_0) = \prod_{i=1}^n p(Y_i = y_i \,|\,  X_n = x_n, \dots, X_0 = x_0)$$
- **A2.2.** $p(Y_i = y_i \,|\, X_n = x_n, \dots, X_0 = x_0) = p(Y_i = y_i \,|\, X_i = x_i)$.

My question is now about the relation between assumption **A2.** and **A2.1.**/**A2.2.**. To me it is clear that the former is implied by the latter two. But I can't see if the other direction is true as well. More specifically:

1. Generally, does **A2.** imply **A2.1.**/**A2.2.**?
2. Does **A2.** imply **A2.1.**/**A2.2.** when **A1.** holds?
3. (Minor) Is there a specific name for assumption **A2.** and **A2.2.**. I provided names for **A1.** and **A2.1.**, but I don't recognise the former as known properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the first question is "yes", so, *a fortiori*, so is the answer to the second.

Note that
\begin{align}
p(Y_j = y_j\,|\, &X_n = x_n, \dots, X_0 = x_0)=\\
&\sum_{y_1,\dots,y_{j-1}\\
        y_{j+1},\dots,y_n}p(Y_1 = y_1, \dots, Y_n = y_n \,|\, X_n = x_n, \dots, X_0 = x_0)
\end{align}
and
$$
p(Y_j = y_j \,|\, X_j = x_j)=\sum_{y_1,\dots,y_{j-1}\\
        y_{j+1},\dots,y_n}\prod_{i=1}^n p(Y_i = y_i \,|\, X_i = x_i)\ .
$$
Therefore, if
\begin{align}
p(Y_1 = y_1, \dots, Y_n = y_n \,|\, X_n = x_n, \dots, &X_0 = x_0) =\\
 &\prod_{i=1}^n p(Y_i = y_i \,|\, X_i = x_i)
\end{align}
(i.e. **A2.** holds), then by summing both sides of this equation over $\ y_1,\dots,$$\,y_{j-1},y_{j+1},\dots,y_n\ $, we get
$$
p(Y_j = y_j\,|\, X_n = x_n, \dots, X_0 = x_0)=p(Y_j = y_j \,|\, X_j = x_j)\ ,
$$
which is **A2.2.**.  Now substituting $\ p(Y_i = y_i\,|\, X_n = x_n, \dots, X_0 = x_0)\ $ for $\ p(Y_i = y_i \,|\, X_i = x_i)\ $ back in the product on the left side of **A2.** gives
\begin{align}
p(Y_1 = y_1, \dots, Y_n = y_n \,|\, &X_n = x_n, \dots, X_0 = x_0) =\\
&\prod_{i=1}^n p(Y_i = y_i\,|\, X_n = x_n, \dots, X_0 = x_0)\ ,
\end{align}
which is **A2.1.**.

In early papers on Hidden Markov Models, their output $\ Y\ $ was referred to as "a probabilistic function" of the underlying hidden Markov chain $\ X\ $, and I believe it's the property **A2.** that constitutes the definition of what it means to be "a probabilistic function".  Apart from that possibility (of which I'm not entirely certain), I know of no other names for either **A2.** or **A2.2.**.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I was looking for.